# React private route with Firebase federated auth?

Tags: firebase-authentication, react-router-dom

I've seen a lot of examples on how to implement private routes with classic email/password authentication, but I'm not sure how to do the same with **federated** auth that **redirects** to the provider's UI. Meaning to say, when the auth provider redirects back to the app, is there a way to figure out what the private route that got replaced by the auth route was?

unauthenticated user -> /some-private-route -> /login -> /facebook -> /login -> how to get to /some-private-route?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like adding a private route URL to the login page is sufficient to maintain the state between the request and redirect result.

unauthenticated user -> /some-private-route -> /login?redirect_uri=/some-private-route -> /facebook -> /login?redirect_uri=/some-private-route -> /some-private-route